# Camel properties component can't parse nested yaml?

Tags: yaml, apache-camel

I have some yaml I'm trying to parse using Camel's property component:

```
a.b: myVal

c:
  d: myOtherVal
```

When I try to reference these in a route, {{a.b}} works but not {{c.d}}. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: I don't know Apache Camel but be aware that in YAML, nested mappings do not automatically concatenate their keys. So your YAML file does *not* contain a key `c.d`; it contains a key `c` whose value is a nested mapping containing the key `d`. Some frameworks, like e.g. Spring, do post-processing that flattens the structure in a way that it resembles a Java Properties file, which does create the key `c.d`. Does Camel state that it does similar processing?

Comment: I think you're right. I wasn't able to find anything stating as much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @flyx I think it's the case that camel doesn't do any preprocessing on yml files like Spring does.